# Fresnel Integral with angle involving $\cot \alpha$

Tags: analysis

I am working on fractional Hilbert transform $$\frac{e^{-i\frac{t^2}{2}\cot\alpha}}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\frac{x^2}{2}\cot\alpha}\frac{f(x)}{t-x}dx,$$ while working on this transform I came across the Fresnel integral $$\int_{-1}^{1}e^{i\frac{x^2}{2}\cot\alpha}dx.$$
Is this Fresnel integral equal to $(1+i)\sqrt\frac{1}{\cot\alpha}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: *Welcome to the site !* For any next question, explain your workings and tell where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing a gaussian integral
$$\int e^{i\frac{x^2}{2}\cot\alpha}\,dx=-\frac{(-1)^{3/4}}{2}  \sqrt{\pi\sin (2 \alpha )}\, \sec (\alpha )\,\,
   \text{erfi}\left(\frac{(-1)^{1/4}  \cos (\alpha )}{\sqrt{\sin (2 \alpha
   )}}x\right)$$
Without any restriction about $\alpha$, then
$$\int_{-1}^{+1}e^{i\frac{x^2}{2}\cot\alpha}\,dx=$$ $$(1-i) \sqrt{\frac \pi 2 } \sec (\alpha ) \sqrt{\sin (2\alpha ) }\,\,
   \text{erfi}\left(\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right) \csc (\alpha )
   \sqrt{\frac 12\sin (2\alpha ) }\right)$$

Assuming $0 <\alpha <\frac \pi 2$, this write
$$\int_{-1}^{+1}e^{i\frac{x^2}{2}\cot\alpha}\,dx=(1-i) \sqrt{\pi\tan (\alpha )}\,\,
   \text{erfi}\left(\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right) \sqrt{\cot (\alpha
   )}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It solved my problem.

Comment: It means that $C(x)+iS(x)$ is equal to gaussian integral? where $C$ and $S$ are Fresnel cos and sin integrals respectively.